# How to use update_or_create with defaults argument

Tags: django, django-models

I have the model League

```
class League(models.Model):                         
    league = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)                                                    
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country_code = models.ForeignKey("Country",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)                
    season = models.ForeignKey("Season", null=True,on_delete = models.SET_NULL, to_field = "season")                                                
    season_start = models.DateField(null = True)    season_end = models.DateField(null = True)      
    league_logo = models.URLField(null = True)      league_flag = models.URLField(null = True)      
    standings = models.IntegerField(null=True)          
    is_current = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I created objects from this model. After it i needed to add some additional fields to League model after adding those fields League object became so

```
class League(models.Model):                         
    league = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)                                                    
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country_code = models.ForeignKey("Country",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)                
    season = models.ForeignKey("Season", null=True,on_delete = models.SET_NULL, to_field = "season")                                                
    season_start = models.DateField(null = True)    season_end = models.DateField(null = True)      
    league_logo = models.URLField(null = True)      league_flag = models.URLField(null = True)      
    standings = models.IntegerField(null=True)          
    is_current = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    cover_standings = models.BooleanField(null=True)                                                   
    cover_fixtures_events = models.BooleanField(null=True)                                           
    cover_fixtures_lineups = models.BooleanField(null=True)                                         
    cover_fixtures_statistics = models.BooleanField(null=True)                                      
    cover_fixtures_players_statistics = models.BooleanField(null=True)                               
    cover_players = models.BooleanField(null=True)                                                  
    cover_topScorers = models.BooleanField(null=True)                                               
    cover_predictions = models.BooleanField(null=True)                                              
    cover_odds = models.BooleanField(null=True)     
    lastModified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I did migrations and added these fields to db schema. Now i want to add to these added fields values. I read about 
**update_or_create** method and tried to use it for updating League model objects

```
leagues_json = json.load(leagues_all)           
data_json = leagues_json["api"]["leagues"]      
for item in data_json:                              
    league_id = item["league_id"]                   
    league_name = item["name"]                      country_q =Country.objects.get(country = item["country"])                                          
    season = Season.objects.get(season = item["season"])                                            
    season_start = item["season_start"]             
    season_end = item["season_end"]                  
    league_logo = item["logo"]                      
    league_flag = item["flag"]                        
    standings = item["standings"]                   
    is_current = item["is_current"]
    coverage_standings = item["coverage"]["standings"]                                              
    coverage_fixtures_events = item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["events"]                               
    coverage_fixtures_lineups = item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["lineups"]                             
    coverage_fixtures_statistics = item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["statistics"]                       
    coverage_fixtures_plaers_statistics = item["coverage"]["fixtures"]["players_statistics"]       
   coverage_players = item["coverage"]["players"]                                                   
   coverage_topScorers = item["coverage"]["topScorers"]                                              
   coverage_predictions = item["coverage"]["predictions"]
   coverage_odds = item["coverage"]["odds"]
   b = League.objects.update_or_create(league = league_id,
   league_name = league_name,
   country_code = country_q,season = season,
   season_start = season_start,
   season_end = season_end,
   league_logo = league_logo,
   league_flag = league_flag,
   standings = standings,
   is_current = is_current,
   cover_standings = coverage_standings, 
   cover_fixtures_events = coverage_fixtures_events,
   cover_fixtures_lineups = coverage_fixtures_lineups,
   cover_fixtures_statistics= coverage_fixtures_statistics, 
   cover_fixtures_players_statistics = coverage_fixtures_players_statistics,
   cover_players= coverage_players,
   cover_topScorers = coverage_topScorers,
   cover_predictions = coverage_predictions, 
   cover_odds = coverage_odds)
```

While i am trying to update objects by above method i get an error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dataflow_league_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (league)=(1) already exists.
```

I read about defaults argument of **update_or_create** method but didn't understand how to useit in my case. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `update_or_create` like this, first of all, your code will search the row in db with that all parameters.
I think you want to search league by league id and it works like this

You create the dict by any way of defaults, I just copy your code

```
defaults = dict(
league_name=league_name,
country_code=country_q,
season=season,
season_start=season_start,
season_end=season_end,
league_logo=league_logo,
league_flag=league_flag,
standings=standings,
is_current=is_current,
cover_standings=coverage_standings,
cover_fixtures_events=coverage_fixtures_events,
cover_fixtures_lineups=coverage_fixtures_lineups,
cover_fixtures_statistics=coverage_fixtures_statistics,
cover_fixtures_players_statistics=coverage_fixtures_players_statistics,
cover_players=coverage_players,
cover_topScorers=coverage_topScorers,
cover_predictions=coverage_predictions,
cover_odds=coverage_odds)
```

And use this defaults to update or create league with particular id

```
League.objects.update_or_create(defaults=defaults, league=league_id)
```

This code will find league with league_id and update it with data which you passed as the defaults parameter

OR

This code will create new league with that id and these params

Comment: I should pass to defaults dict only those fields which i want to update ?

Comment: Yes, if you already have League with that id `league=league_id`, you will update this data from defaults, if you don't have League with that id, you will create the row with this data from defaults and with that  `league=league_id`

Comment: In the func update_or_create
defaults -- for update/create
**kwargs -- for lookup/create

Comment: Thank you i will try it. Unfortunately i didnt have rights to flag you answer

Comment: Why? Can you put ✓ the flag to my answer? It's available for everybody who created the question

Comment: No, flaging answers available only for users who have more than 15 user points. But after that question was answered by you i earned some weight and now i can flag it. I will flag it and vote for my question too to increase my authority too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use update_or_create like this
if  exist, it return obj and created false
if not exist, it return obj and created true.

```
 obj, created = League.objects.update_or_create(defaults=defaults, league=league_id)
```